# maven ant regex to insert xml text

Tags: java, regex, xml, maven, ant

I am trying to insert an xml element into an xml file via maven ant plugin and the replaceregexp task.

This is how it looks originally:

```
  <types>
    <xs:schema>
       <xs:import namespace='http://biz.funct.com/c/data/v4_6'
       schemaLocation='commoncomplexelements.xsd' />
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema>
       <xs:import namespace='http://biz.funct.com/b/data/v1_5'
       schemaLocation='location.xsd' />
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema>
       <xs:import namespace='http://biz.funct.com/location/a/data/v1_5'
       schemaLocation='location-validcodes.xsd' />
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema>
       <xs:import namespace='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'
       schemaLocation='oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' />
    </xs:schema>  
  </types>
```

And this is how it should look in the end:

```
  <types>
    <xs:schema>
       <xs:import namespace='http://biz.funct.com/c/data/v4_6'
       schemaLocation='commoncomplexelements.xsd' />
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema>
       <xs:import namespace='http://biz.funct.com/b/data/v1_5'
       schemaLocation='location.xsd' />
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema>
       <xs:import namespace='http://biz.funct.com/location/a/data/v1_5'
       schemaLocation='location-validcodes.xsd' />
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema>
        <xs:import namespace='http://biz.funct.com/location/d/data/v1_5'
            schemaLocation='newfile.xsd' />
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema>
       <xs:import namespace='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'
       schemaLocation='oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' />
    </xs:schema>  
  </types>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>insert-xml</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target name="Insert xml">
                            <replaceregexp flags="m">
                              <regexp pattern="\&lt;xs:schema\&gt;(.*)\&lt;/xs:schema\&gt;"/>
                              <substitution expression="hello"/>
                              <filelist 
                                  id="" 
                                  dir="${project.build.directory}/f"
                                  files="ServiceInterface.wsdl"/> 
                            </replaceregexp>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Any help in getting the correct regexp would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the actual issue? btw, if you are trying to insert a node into the second to last position as is apparent, that regex definitely won't do it, as it would target everything in between `<types>...</types>`

Comment: @sweaver2112 the issue is getting the right regex. I edited the question trying to clarify it. I know the one I have doesn't work, I spent quite a lot of time testing but left a simple example. I'm affraid my regex skills are very limited.

Comment: so you want to target the spot just before the last schema tag?

Comment: @sweaver2112 yep, and insert the element that differs from the first to the second xml block.

Comment: you could try  `(?=<xs:schema>(?:(?!<\/xs:schema>).)+<\/xs:schema>\s*<\/types>)` https://regex101.com/r/letGLw/2/ and just replace the "match" (which is only a position which is anchored by that last </types>) with your substring. Again, you've not described the conditions or goals, but only given a single input/output example, so it's hard to know what you want here.

Comment: @sweaver2112 Thanks, that helped. I'd consider it a valid answer if you are interested in posting it as such. I think the question is clear enough as it is. I have two blocks of text and I want the first to look like the second after it has been run through a replaceregexp task on the maven ant run plugin. You seemed to get it, otherwise you wouldn't have given me a valid answer. Having said that, I will try to be more clearer when posting future questions.

Comment: no problem just wasn't sure if that  namespace string mattered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try `(?=<xs:schema>(?:(?!<\/xs:schema>).)+<\/xs:schema>\s*<\/type‌​s>) regex101.com/r/letGLw/2` and just replace the "match" (which is zero-width - a position only, anchored by that last `</types>`) with your replacement string.

https://regex101.com/r/letGLw/2/